# Bootstrap: Vertically center label in form-group

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, valign

I have a form-group inside a horizontal form. In this form-group, the right element is higher than the left one. For this reason, I want to center the left element vertically in its row. For instance:

```xml
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> <!-- higher element -->
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        <br>Random stuff
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`Email1` is currently shown at the top of its own row as can be seen in [this plunker snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/Om2f7LdxiorBrmbJYsVC).

EDIT: So to clarify my intentions, this is the current state:

[image]

And this is what I would like to have (the blue area is the previously mentioned "row"):

[image]

Comment: So you want the `label` to appear right on the left of the `input` field regarding the size of the screen? Correct me if Im wrong?

Comment: Actually, this is what already happens. Instead, the `label` should appear right between the `input` and the text `Random stuff`.

Comment: Im working on this now, but just a request could you supply a picture at least a rough drawing of what you want to appear? Thanks.

Comment: According to the link you provided the left element you are referring was the `label` if you expand the window it appears on the left of the the `input`. This part is not very clear if you will ask me. **I want to center the left element vertically in terms of the whole row** How do you exactly want it to appear? Your question is unclear. Please provide a picture or rewrite your question so I could help you.

Comment: @GreenFox I just update the description to clarify things.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. Does this have to go for both `input`?

Comment: Also Im curious, why do you exactly want it to be this way? Coz in my opinion its not a very neat way to create a `form`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are ready to drop support for some "old" browsers, you can use the flexbox features (see [caniuse.com flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex))

```
<div class="form-group flex-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    <br>Random stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex-group {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
  }
  .form-horizontal .flex-group .control-label {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BQ6C4LGiL4oe1ZQTQ3Ys

Comment: This is the first thing that actually worked for me after looking at a bunch of similar questions. Thanks Sherbrow

Answer (score 2):

You could just set the line-height equal to the height using CSS.
Also, don't repeat domain IDs, you can only use id="inputEmail3" once. I changed both IDs to fit the text.

CSS

```
label[for="inputEmail3"]{
    height: 74px;
    line-height: 74px;
}
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> <!-- higher element -->
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        <br>Random stuff
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail2" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want label1 to drop down as in your image, can't you just add a class giving it some padding-top? Like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/eqhh47bh/)

Not clear on whether you want all dropped down or just label1.

CSS

```
.label1{padding-top:35px !important}
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="label1 col-sm-2 control-label">Email1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10"> <!-- higher element -->
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    <br>Random stuff
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email2</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10"> 
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.form-horizontal .vertically-aligned-label {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to control this if viewed on a small device, as the label will be on top of the input.

I have added some more bootstrap to cover this for you.

See in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/z8nrv5bm/5/)**.

```
<div class="container block ">

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-0">    
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row block bg-info form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="label1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Email1</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 col-xs-push-1"> <!-- higher element -->
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        <br>Random stuff
        <br>Random stuff 
        <br>Random stuff  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row block bg-info form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="label2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Email2</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 col-xs-push-1"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        </div>
</form> 
</div>
</div>
```

[image]